# add a virtual column to a reflected table

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have a class

```
class TableA(Base):
    __table__ = table_a
    __mapper_args__ = {
            'primary_key':[table_a.pk,],
            }
```

and want to add a transform as a column that will be seen when querying (I only have read access, so no writing is necessary)

```
new_col = func.regexp_substr(table_a.original, r'[^-]*').label("new_col")
```

Is there a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Using `column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property):

```
class TableA(Base):
    __table__ = table_a
    __mapper_args__ = {
            'primary_key':[table_a.pk,],
            }

    # new_col = column_property(func.regexp_substr(original, r'[^-]*'))  # or
    new_col = column_property(func.regexp_substr(table_a.c.original, r'[^-]*'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.FetchedValue

```
class TableA(Base):
    ........
    new_col = Column(DB.String, FetchedValue())
    ........
```