# In SQLAlchemy, can not virtual columns be created in modle class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, I want to put a virtual column into a modle class.

```
class tableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tableA'

    code = Column('code', String(10), primary_key=True)
    date_a = Column(DateTime)
    date_b = Column(DateTime)
    date_d = Column(func.DATEDIFF(date_a, date_b))
```

error

Comment: Edit typo modle >> model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add a virtual column to a reflected table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492764/add-a-virtual-column-to-a-reflected-table)